# Redirect translated taxonomy to taxonomy file

Tags: php, wordpress

I create a taxonomy to my CPT, which I use taxonomy-categories-services.php and taxonomy-categories-technology.php as archive for this taxonomies. 
The problem is that I need that the translations goes to this file and use the same archive. There's a way to do this?

```
register_taxonomy( 'categories', 'partners', array(
       'hierarchical' => true, 
       'label' => 'Categories', 
       'singular_label' => 'Category', 
       'has_archive' => true,
       'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'partners','with_front' => false )
       )
   );
```

Comment: which translation plugin you are using?

Comment: I have Multisite Language Switcher

Comment: get_post_meta($post->ID, '_short_summary_meta_box', true); This is what I am using. so for get translation you are able to use your slug with '_' . It Will give you the translation string.